# How do I make something print if the input is a number is between 2 different numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, I want to be able to have an input where if a number is between 2 numbers, such as if a number is between 2-8 , it prints "Confirmed.", So if the input is 4,5,6,7 or 8 it will do that.

I've tried this code only, because I couldn't think of anything else.

```py
  if Distance > 1 and < 9:
    print("You should ride your bike.")
```

I want it to print out "You should ride your bike" if the inputted number is between 2 and 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do:

```
if 1 < Distance < 9:
    print("You should ride your bike.")
```

Answer (score 1):

i].you can use `and` operator

```
if Distance > 1 and Distance < 9:
    print("You should ride your bike.")
```

ii].Simple one

```
if 1 < Distance < 9:
    print("You should ride your bike.")
```